# javascript determine function definition line number

Tags: javascript, exception

This question is about determining the line number of the function >definition<
in its source file.  Just to be clear:

It is NOT about determining the line number of a caller - been there, done that. It is NOT about determining the CURRENT line number - been there, done that. It is NOT about examining the source code for the function - been there, done that. It is NOT about finding the name/url of the file when a break occurs and the line number in that file of the offender at that time - been there done that. It is NOT about using Chrome/Firefox/DragonFly Dev Tools to locate the offender.  It is NOT about PHP, etc.  Original source code can not be modified - only the exception handler (or the constructor which is being passed the function/anonymous function).

Context - the code is already in a [dump information routine called from a] catch block.  I am trying to dump the specific offending line.
I have the offending line number in the source file; I have the offending function's code parsed into lines/line numbers. Thus I have the offset INTO the function (which is often an anonymous function).  If I can somehow determine the line number where a function was defined (without forcing another exception), then the offset allows me to dump the offending line.
But the rub is getting the origin from which to compute the offset into
the function.

Possibilities of execution context for determining this include:
1) when the (anonymous) function is referenced/defined as part of a constructor (note: referenced/defined, NOT called) - at which time, if the line number of the >definition< in its source can be determined, it can be saved in the object
being constructed and then used later in the exception handler.
2) in the exception handler.

Sorry about the verbiage, but there are a lot of answers out there which seemingly (via search heuristics) address this, but in fact, none of them address the specific problem here.

Any suggestions, any at all, or is this hunting for a unicorn?
Thx (1138)

Comment: (Nice reference there at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the information available within a `catch` block that will tell you what line in the source file the function containing that `catch` block starts on. I'm afraid you are indeed hunting for a unicorn.

You could use a pre-processor on the code that would add that information for you, using a parser like Esprima or by writing yourself a Babel plugin to do it. They have access to the necessary semantic and textual information to inject the number of the source line starting the function into the call to your "dump information" function.

Comment: A worthy suggestion, indeed.  However, as you probably surmised, this is part of a library and that would probably be too much of a dependency for using it.  Still, I will look into the possibility of using it in the library's SDK/browser extension - a place where it is natural to dump out more excrutiating detail..  Thank you.